# Record being inserted twice in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a normal blogpost in my database and for some reason it is inserting the same record twice. I am giving out both my html and php code down below.

```
<?php


if(isset($_POST["post"]))
{
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","yomadsdata");
    $post = $_POST["post"];
    $heading = $_POST["heading"];

    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO blogposts(blog_heading,blog_post) value 
    ('$heading','$post')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "New post created successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    }

    else
   {
        echo "Come in through proper ways.";
   }

   ?>
```

Comment: You called $conn->query twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute the query twice `$conn->query($sql)`. You can remove the `$result` since you execute query in `if`

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO blogposts(blog_heading,blog_post) value ('$heading','$post')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New post created successfully";
}
```

Or you can try this

```
if ($result) {
        echo "New post created successfully";
    }
```

Comment: ...but I am not assigning the value of the sql statement in $result variable. How is that an execution?

Comment: @Goldensquare using `$conn->query() ` will execute the query